# Scrape website with html agility pack,find class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, scrape

i am tring to get som data, from a html string using HTML Agility pack.

The row string[] i am trying to get the data from returns innerhtml like this:

```
<td class="street">Riksdagen</td>
<td class="number">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="number">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="postalcode">100 12</td>
<td class="locality">Stockholm</td>
<td class="region_code">018001</td>
<td class="county">Stockholm</td>
<td class="namnkommun">Stockholm</td>
```

How can i assign each class to the right addressDataModel propery?

```
var row = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='thetable']/tr");

    foreach (var rowItem in row)
    {
        var addressDataModel = new AddressDataModel
        {
            street = rowItem.FirstChild.InnerText,
            zipCodeFrom = // Next item,
            zipCodeTo = // Next item,
            zipCode = // Next item,
            locality = // Next item,
            regionCode = // Next item,
            state = // Next item,
            county = // Next item
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this (make sure the node exists before use InnerText prop):

```
var addressDataModel = new AddressDataModel
    {
        street = rowItem.SelectSingleNode("./td[@class='street']").InnerText,
        zipCodeFrom = // Next item,
        zipCodeTo = // Next item,
        zipCode = // Next item,
        locality = // Next item,
        regionCode = // Next item,
        state = // Next item,
        county = rowItem.SelectSingleNode("./td[@class='county']").InnerText
    };
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: well XPATH will not work if website having invalid syntax or mockup. RegEx is another option

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to this if you don't want to use Xpath :

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlContent = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        htmlContent.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

        if (htmlContent.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode n in htmlContent.DocumentNode.Descendants("div"))
            {
                if (n.HasAttributes && n.Attributes["class"] != null)
                {
                    if (n.Attributes["class"].Value == "className")
                    {
                      // Do something
                    } 
                }                 
            }
        }
```